# Are unused Stimpaks and RadAways returned to storage upon explorer return to the vault?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've just sent out an explorer but forgot to give him a good armor. I wanted to call him back so I can give him the armor, but I gave him a number of Stimpaks and RadAways.

**If unused, will these items be returned to storage or will they go to waste?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Stimpaks and radaways will go back into storage, but will not exceed capacity.

For example, let's say you have a capacity of 25 stimpaks. You send all of them out with an explorer. While they are exploring, your medbay creates 6 more stimpaks and places them in storage. If the explorer comes back into the vault with 25 stimpaks, you will end up with only 25 stimpaks in storage because while 6 + 25 = 31, the 6 stimpaks above capacity are discarded, leaving you with your capacity of 25 stimpaks.

Answer (score 2):

The leftover stim and med packs remain with the dweller. You can click on the dweller to select them and then - or + packs that the dweller is carrying.